# Oracle - PreparedStatement Command not properly Ended

Tags: prepared-statement, apostrophe

I am using `Oracle 11g`, and when I try to create a select statement with an `apostrophe`, I get the following error.

Is the prepared statement suppose to take care of apostrophes or should I do it?
Is there a way to see the query just before execution (`with true values instead of '?') ?`

Comment: `prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABLE T" +
                            "WHERE T.COL1 = ? " +
                            "AND T.COL2 = ? " +
                            "AND T.COL3 = ? ", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);`

Comment: Loop over parameters with setString(index, str);    And then executeQuery();

Comment: I keep getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lacking a space between the name of the table (`T`) and `WHERE`. Thus the SQL that gets executed looks something like this `SELECT * FROM TABLE TWHERE T.COL1 = '<somevalue>' AND T.COL2 = '<somevalue>' AND T.COL3 = '<somevalue>'` - note the **TWHERE**.